# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'tenant_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I am trying to get a list of products matching a vendor_id.  The tables Products and Vendors have a many to many relationship, therefore I created a pivot table with the fields vendor_id and product_id.

The Eloquent query below:

```
Product::with('brand','tax')
                ->has('vendors')
                ->where('vendor_id',$vendor_id)
                ->get();
```

Although not visible in the query, I have a trait BelongsToTenant that automatically appends ->where(tenant,tenant_id) to each model, and both tables have the field tenant_id. I think I'm getting this error because this trait exists in both the Models (Product and Vendor). I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Where clause is ambiguous because the `products` table and the group table `vendors` has the `vendor_id` column.  If you have multiple same column on your query, then mention the table name :

```
Product::with('brand','tax')
       ->has('vendors')
       ->where('products.vendor_id',$vendor_id)
       ->get();
```